# JavaFX Spinner should only decrement/increment by one value when holding the mouse pressed

Tags: java, javafx, spinner

When I hold the increment/decrement buttons of the spinner, the value inside the Spinner is incrementing/decrementing very fast, but I only want it to increment/decrement one time (one Integer down/up) every time I hold the arrows of the Spinner.

I want that holding the arrows should behave the same as clicking the arrows of the Spinner.

Is there a solution to this?

I already tried the "On Mouse Clicked" and the "On Mouse Pressed" Events.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 4):

Simply setting the repeat delay to `Duration.INDEFINITE` seems to work:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(0,100,1);

        spinner.setRepeatDelay(Duration.INDEFINITE);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(spinner);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 180);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Something new learned.